# JSON parsing issue (get attributes)

Tags: json, gson

I have parsed JSON using GSON, and out of object got the element I needed:

```
JsonObject obj=str.getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement search=obj.get("value");
```

Now, the GSON JsonElement 'search' contains following JSON:

```
[{"title":"John Lennon","snippet":"English musician, singer"}]
```

Formatted:

```
[
    {
        "title": "John Lennon",
        "snippet": "English musician, singer",
    }
]
```

I need to extract out following two values title and snippet.
How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you can use [`getAsJsonArray()`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#getAsJsonArray--)

```
JsonObject obj= str.getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement search= obj.get("value").getAsJsonArray().get(0)

search.get("title") //John Lennon
```

and

```
search.get("snippet") // English musician, singer
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JsonElement#getAsJsonArray()`:

```
JsonElement firstEntry = search.getAsJsonArray().get(0);
firstEntry.get("title") // => John Lennon
firstEntry.get("snippet") // => English musician, singer
```

If it is not certain that the element actually is an array, then use `JsonElement#isJsonArray()` as a pre-condition:

```
if(search.isJsonArray()) {
    JsonElement firstEntry = search.getAsJsonArray().get(0);
    firstEntry.get("title") // => John Lennon
    firstEntry.get("snippet") // => English musician, singer
}
```